# Are byte and byte-string the same thing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, byte

The function that I am trying to run requires the input of a byte-string, I converted the string to byte by using this down below. However the function does not work. Not sure if it is an issue with the package I am using or if the way I converted the string into bytes is not a byte string.

```
message = "AJKANBKJBD9a0234Nkoasldkfjan0OKNKnlkasdf"
b = message.encode("utf-8")
function_example(b)
```

Comment: Yes that is a byte string. You can also just use `b'abd'` directly. The leading b indicates a byte string as opposed to a Unicode string.  Are you getting an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes in python, both are the same. to cross-check for further queries you could use type as follows

```
message = "AJKANBKJBD9a0234Nkoasldkfjan0OKNKnlkasdf"
b = message.encode("utf-8")
isSame = (type(b) == type(b"AJKANBKJBD9a0234Nkoasldkfjan0OKNKnlkasdf"))
print(isSame)
```